# Case in point or for example

Tags: meaning, phrase-choice

1. What is the difference between 'case in point' and 'for example'
2. Is case in point or for example more appropriate in the sentence below:

Ability has never been related to a person’s gender, a good **case in point** is that I got a part-time job in which I completed more questionnaires per day than male colleagues.

Ability has never been related to a person’s gender, **for example**, I got a part-time job in which I completed more questionnaires per day than male colleagues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you complicate the sentence by "a good case in point is that" when you can simply say "for example"? Unless you want to stress that the example you are going to give is really good. They both mean the same, I find the former a little excessive.

"for example" is undoubtedly more popular.

I never seen case in point being used in the middle of a sentence...

> Me, completing more questionnaires per day than male colleagues while working part-time, **is a good case in point**.

> **A good case in point would be** me, who ...

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. The question was not which is better or more popular, it was what's the difference in meaning. Sure there must be a nuance between the two.